# Increase the size of /dev/shm in Azure ML Studio

Tags: python, azure, scikit-learn, joblib, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to execute the following code in Azure ML Studio notebook:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold, cross_val_score

for C in np.linspace(0.01, 0.2, 30):
    cv = KFold(n=X_train.shape[0], n_folds=7, shuffle=True, random_state=12345)
    clf = LogisticRegression(C=C, random_state=12345)
    print C, sum(cross_val_score(clf, X_train_scaled, y_train, scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv, n_jobs=2)) / 7.0
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to save <type 'numpy.ndarray'> to .npy file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nbcommon/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 271, in save
    obj, filename = self._write_array(obj, filename)
  File "/home/nbcommon/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 231, in _write_array
    self.np.save(filename, array)
  File "/home/nbcommon/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 491, in save
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/home/nbcommon/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 585, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
IOError: 19834920 requested and 8384502 written

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-9740e9942629> in <module>()
      6     cv = KFold(n=X_train.shape[0], n_folds=7, shuffle=True, random_state=12345)
      7     clf = LogisticRegression(C=C, random_state=12345)
----> 8     print C, sum(cross_val_score(clf, X_train_scaled, y_train, scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv, n_jobs=2)) / 7.0

/home/nbcommon/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.pyc in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
   1431                                               train, test, verbose, None,
   1432                                               fit_params)
-> 1433                       for train, test in cv)
   1434     return np.array(scores)[:, 0]
   1435 

/home/nbcommon/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __call__(self, iterable)
    808                 # consumption.
    809                 self._iterating = False
--> 810             self.retrieve()
    811             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    812             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

/home/nbcommon/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in retrieve(self)
    725                 job = self._jobs.pop(0)
    726             try:
--> 727                 self._output.extend(job.get())
    728             except tuple(self.exceptions) as exception:
    729                 # Stop dispatching any new job in the async callback thread

/home/nbcommon/env/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
    565             return self._value
    566         else:
--> 567             raise self._value
    568 
    569     def _set(self, i, obj):

IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

With `n_jobs=1` it works fine.

I think this is because `joblib` library tries to save my data to `/dev/shm`. The problem is that it has only 64M capacity:

```
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none               786G  111G  636G  15% /
tmpfs               56G     0   56G   0% /dev
shm                 64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               56G     0   56G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/crypt  786G  111G  636G  15% /etc/hosts
```

I can't change this folder by setting `JOBLIB_TEMP_FOLDER` environment variable (`export` doesn't work).

```
In [35]: X_train_scaled.nbytes

Out[35]: 158679360
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/dev/shm` is a virtual filesystem for passing data between programs that implementation of traditional shared memory on Linux.

So you could not increase it via set up some options on Application Layout.

But for example, you can remount `/dev/shm` with 8G size in Linux Shell with administrator permission like `root` as follows.

`mount -o remount,size=8G /dev/shm`

However, it seems that Azure ML studio not support remote access via SSH protocol, so the feasible plan is upgrade the standard tier if using free tier at present.

Comment: I tried to ask this question on msdn forums, and I think they will increase the size of /dev/shm in the future.
I decided just to copy the data and run ThreadPool instead of joblib as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter Pan pointed out, you generally cannot fix this from your Python code but instead when starting the Docker container.

Nowadays, you can do this using Azure ML Studio API.
You have to supply the `--shm_size` to the Docker run command.
You can do this using the Azure ML studio API by creating a `DockerConfiguration` object like this:

```
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core import ScriptRunConfig
from azureml.core.runconfig import DockerConfiguration
    
    
# Specify VM and Python environment:
my_env = Environment.from_conda_specification(name='my-test-env', file_path=PATH_TO_YAML_FILE)
my_env.docker.base_image = 'mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi3.1.2-cuda10.2-cudnn7-ubuntu18.04'
    
docker_config = DockerConfiguration(use_docker=True, shm_size='32g')
    
# Finally, use the environment in the ScriptRunConfig:
src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=DEPLOY_CONTAINER_FOLDER_PATH,
                      script=SCRIPT_FILE_TO_EXECUTE,
                      arguments=EXECUTE_ARGUMENTS,
                      compute_target=compute_target,
                      environment=my_env,
                      docker_runtime_config=docker_config)
```

Here the shared memory size is set to 32 gigabytes.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/569816/custom-argument-pass-to-docker-container-azure-ml.html)

[Docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)